# Regular Expression to match only one angle bracket

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches the '>' in

```
a > b
>
b>
...
```

but not two or more angled brackets, i.e. it should **not** match

```
a>>b
>>
b>>
...
```

I was sure to do that with lookaheads or lookbehinds, but for some reason neither

```
\>(?!\>)
```

nor

```
(?<!\>)\>
```

work..?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the kinds of "regular" expressions you mean, as this doesn't sound like an actual regular language to me.

Answer (score 4):

Perl syntax:

```
/(?<!>)>(?!>)/
```

Without using lookahead or lookbehind:

```
/(?:^|[^>])>(?:[^>]|$)/
```

Answer (score 1):

perreal's first regex is correct. However, the second regex given in that answer subtly fails in one condition. Since it captures characters both before and after, two `>`s separated by a single character will not both be found.

Here is a regex which only uses forward lookaheads and doesn't have that problem:

```
(?:^|[^>])(>)(?:$|(?!>))
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/8pxI27g3y78_45rs)

Comment: It would be cleaner to write `(?:^|[^>])(>)(?=$|[^>])`, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you use the lookahead, you're matching the second `>` (there's no `>` after the second `>`), and when you're using the lookbehind, you're matching the first `>`.

You could probably use this:

```
[^>]>[^>]
```

There's a `>`, with no `>` before or after it.

But I think that to suit what you exactly need, need to use lookaheads and lookbehinds both:

```
(?<!>)>(?!>)
```

Comment: There is no reason to escape `>`. It is not a special regex character.

Comment: @Treecj Could you perhaps mark an answer as accepted to indicate that your problem had been solved? ^^