# Regex find < or > not << or >>

Tags: regex

I Am struggling to build a regex that matches < or > but not << or >>

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: See [*Regular Expression to match only one angle bracket*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747723/regular-expression-to-match-only-one-angle-bracket)

Comment: do you want to find the string "< or >" but it should exclude "<< or >>"
is that it?

Comment: use look ahead and look behind assertion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match only one angle bracket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747723/regular-expression-to-match-only-one-angle-bracket)

Comment: @masadwin yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Expression

The regex you're looking for, including your response to masadwin's comment is:

```
(?<!<)<(?!<) or (?<!>)>(?!>)
```

You can look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXx67S/1).

#### Explanation

- `(?<!<)<(?!<)` disallows an opening angled brackets that leads or trails another.
- `or` matches exactly *" or "* text.
- `(?<!>)>(?!>)` here it's the same as for the opening angled bracket, but for the closing one.

Comment: Nice copy of my answer with a weird interpretation of the word `or` ;)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Or not. Your expressions are just from the link that Wiktor put in his comment. From my side, I was doing it in Regex101 by taking into account the OP response to masadwin's comment and writing my answer accordingly. I took my time to understand, write expression and write my message to avoid at best mistakes or a response that do not fit completely. Sorry if you felt copied, but that wasn't the case. Thx for noticing the typo, I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression:

```
(?<!>)>(?!>)
```

It uses a negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and a negative lookahead `(?!)` to match a single `>`.

You can [try it out here in PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29431761fd88366038108ac76b37403b48b166df). It won't work in JavaScript, because it negative lookbehind's are not supported.

---

You could also use this regular expression, which does not need lookaheads or lookbehinds, but matches the next characters around the expression. It will also work at the beginning and the end of the document:

```
(?:[^>]|^)>(?:[^>]|$)
```

```js
var text1 = "nflasnfksalnlk>>lkdmglksanl";
var text2 = "nflasnfksalnlk>lkdmglksanl";
var text3 = ">nflasnfksalnlklkdmglksanl>";
var regex = /(?:[^>]|^)>(?:[^>]|$)/g;

console.log(text1.match(regex));
console.log(text2.match(regex));
console.log(text3.match(regex));
```